# check MFA is enabled for a user using rest api

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, rest

How do I check MFA is enabled for AD users using rest API  loginWithServicePrincipalSecret
is there anyone who can help me out to do this....I want to do this using node sdk like this

```js
require("isomorphic-fetch");
const { UserAgentApplication } = require("msal");
const { ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider");
const { MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/lib/src/MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions");

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "bec52b71-dc94-4577-9f8d-b8536ed0e73d", // Client Id of the registered application
  },
};
const graphScopes = ["user.read", "mail.send"]; // An array of graph scopes

const msalApplication = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
const Options = new MSALAuthenticationProviderOptions(graphScopes);

const authProvider = new ImplicitMSALAuthenticationProvider(
  msalApplication,
  Options
);

const options = {
  authProvider,
};
const Client = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
const client = Client.init(options);
async function test() {
  try {
    let res = await client
      .api("/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails")
      .version("beta")
      .get();
    console.log("res: ", res);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
test();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with [MS Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph),

To Get information of users registered with MFA and hasn't, we can use ***isMfaRegistered*** property in [credentialUserRegistrationDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-list-credentialuserregistrationdetails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) .

> `credentialUserRegistrationDetails` help us to get the details of the
> usage of self-service password reset and multi-factor authentication
> (MFA) for all registered users. Details include user information,
> status of registration, and the authentication method used.
> This is possible programmatically with MS Graph where you will get a JSON reports an can be plugged into other reports or can be represented programmatically itself

**Example:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails
```

**sample output:**

```
{
            "id": "****************************",
            "userPrincipalName": "NKS@nishantsingh.live",
            "userDisplayName": "Nishant Singh",
            "isRegistered": false,
            "isEnabled": true,
            "isCapable": false,
            "isMfaRegistered": true,
            "authMethods": [
                "mobilePhone"
            ]
        }
```

**Sample code for your Node JS,**

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

let res = await client.api('/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails')
    .version('beta')
    .get();
```

To implement your NodeJS code please go through step-by-step guide in [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/node?tutorial-step=1)

Comment: Hari Krishna-- MSFT  Thanks for the response...
can you please guide me what should I have to pass in authProvider 
const options = {
    authProvider,
};
I m really not understanding the documentation it's quite difficult.

Comment: Hi @KainatNaz,In order to use MS Graph we need access token which will be provided by Authentication providers. Authentication providers implement the code required to acquire a token using the Microsoft Authentication Library.Please follow the step by step tutorial shared by me .It has all the steps needed for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, @Hari Krishna-- MSFT Identity

Comment: I am doing this code to get credentialUserRegistrationDetails but I am getting this 

  
ReferenceError: window is not defined**

Comment: hi  @Hari Krishna-- MSFT Identity  here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rvUb.png) please review my code am I doing right code